# Rounding these Radio Buttons (for lack of a better title...)

Tags: radio-button, css

Couldnt think of a great title for this, but basically i have a three radio buttons displayed inline
that are squared. I am trying to round the [radio1][radio2][radio3] outer corners, but i am sure that i am not getting my CSS syntax down correctly. I can get each buttons corners to round individually, but cant seem to figure out how to get just radio1 and radio3's outer corners to round. Each radio has its own id: check it all out here on the jsFiddle.

**//jsfiddle.net/p499h/53/   Please Help!**

Answer (score 0):

You're actually styling the `label`s, so select the adjacent label of the first and last input:

```
#radio1 + label {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#radio3 + label {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p499h/56/)